# Why is there no OnSuccess parameter for executeTransaction() in Realm?

Tags: android, realm

Why are passing callback methods only allowed when using `executeTransactionAsync` and not `executeTransaction`?

Answer (score 0):

Because `executeTransaction` is synchronous, so once the method completes, it is done. That said we have considered adding it, see https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3048

Comment: right, but it would still be synchronous if it were passed an `OnSuccess` or `OnFailure` callback to call when the transaction completed, right?

Answer (score 0):

Local commits update the Realm instance on the looper thread, but the results are not refreshed until the next looper event. (Any results you obtain **after** the local commit **are** up-to-date).

So for changes done in local commit, the expected usage would be to either requery the RealmResults immediately after transaction (less preferred), or use a `RealmChangeListener` to know that the results' internals have changed (more preferred).

That said, the [feature request](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3048) on Melchior's answer for synchronous transaction callback to be notified when the results are already ready was made by me :)